# Python (CSV) sum second column(s) if first column value is the same

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
25,57
25,60
35,60
35,60
35,60
45,70
45,70
...
```

What I need is to create a NEW csv file from this one that keeps only one entry for the first column and sums all the values of the second column where the first column's value is the same.

Example of what I need to make from the above:

```
25, 117
35, 180
45, 140
```

NOTE: I tried pandas grouby and an error came up in my library...

**Tried Code:**

IdandScoreArray = np.empty((27,2), dtype = int)
with f as csvfile:

```
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in csvreader:

        IdScore = (row['user_id'], row['grade_id'])

        IdandScoreArray = np.append(IdandScoreArray, [IdScore], axis = 0)
```

df = pd.DataFrame(IdandScoreArray, columns = ['First', 'Second'])

df.groupbby('First').sum

print df

(something like that)

Comment: "NOTE: I tried pandas grouby and an error came up in my library..." What error? Post the full error message. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: In addition to your error message, please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried? Post that code.

Comment: Dummy solution: create array A for example, read line by line, get values into variables I and J, and then A[I] += J

Comment: Edited with tried code. The code above is very similar to what I ran... I will try to get the panda error up soon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with `groupby` on pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv', header=None)
df = df.groupby([0])[1].sum()
df.to_csv('data/group.csv')
```

based on sample data as input in `data.csv`, i got following output in `group.csv`

```
25,117
35,180
45,140
```